# how to resize textarea width according to text length and height by shift+enter js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on one requirement regarding to textarea dynamic resizing and I cannot find a some nice solution for:

- starting textarea design is one row
- width of textarea is extended by "longest" line of text in textarea (when you start new line, the longest is previous one till the length is longer then new one)
- height of textarea is extended by key combination of shift+enter

The textarea is used as input in bootstrap popup windows.

I am stuck with that and thanks for any idea

Comment: If you can post what you've done so far, and we can help you through the part that you're stuck.

Comment: Hi guys, I tried to add an invisible div element and save the value in it. I am able to get a widht value when the div is extending according to input text. 
But - when I make a new line (shift+enter) and continue by typing, the width of an element is still growing. I have done script which fills the data to div element, also event handler which is listening on key down/up (shift+enter key combination to append text with "\n"  ).
Am I going in the right way?

Comment: @jonsuh

The new line in hidden div is done by <br /> tag and I am able to get the width and height. Then I add converter for html2value and value2html to swap the value <br /> to "\n" for textarea. 
The resizing works, but seems to me quite difficult solution. Is there something easier?